# What is the subject of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

While discussing a piece of scientific writing today, I was confused about the subject (and therefore the singular/plural state) of this sentence.

> The presence of very high cell densities in the embryoid body outgrowths make**s** accurate quantitation of adipogenesis difficult.

What is the subject in this sentence? Is it "presence" or "densities"? What are some rules that I can use to determine the subject of similar sentences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove  the prepositional phrase *of very high cell densities in the embryoid body outgrowths* from the sentence and what is the subject? That word  is still the subject with the prepositional phrase in the sentence.

In addition, which word (*presence* or *densities*)  shows subject-verb agreement? *Makes* is used for third person singular nouns.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto AlanCarmack. In general, when searching for a subject or verb, it is ofteen helpful to drop out qualifying words and phrases. Drop any adjectives or adverbs, and then any phrase that starts with a preposition, like "of ...", "to ...", "for ..." etc. What's left should be the "heart" of the sentence.